# How to provide preferences for hyphenating mixed-language words

Tags: babel, hyphenation, languages, german, english

Let's say we want to typeset long two-language compounds.  We prefer to break such words right after the first-language word is over and before the second-language words starts; if the results get ugly (say, overfull boxes), we wish to allow for breaking also within the single-language parts.

Consider, e.g., *Pipes-and-Filters-Architektur*, *Map/Reduce-Konzept*, *Assume/Guarantee-Spezifikation*, and *Quicksortprinzip* — all of the kind English+German.

Here are our attempts so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}%%% according to the documentation of dehyph-exptl.
%\showoutput
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{
\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Pipes\penalty10000-\penalty2\hskip0pt and\penalty10000-\penalty2\hskip0pt Filters}\penalty10000-\penalty1\hskip0pt Architektur % Pipes-and-Filters-Architektur

\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Map\penalty10000/\penalty2\hskip0pt Reduce}\penalty10000-\penalty1\hskip0pt Konzept % Map/Reduce-Konzept

\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Assume\penalty10000/\penalty2\hskip0pt Guarantee}\penalty10000-\penalty1\hskip0pt Spezifikation % Assume/Guarantee-Spezifikation

\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Quicksort}"-prinzip % Quicksortprinzip
}
\end{document}
```

1. Would this rock?  We get the output (hyphens with `\showhyphens` and penalties with `\showoutput`) which seems right, but I am still not sure.
2. The above typesetting seems quite cumbersome; is there an easier way to reach the same goal? Is `\penalty10000` really necessary between a word and a slash or a dash?
3. How to say in `\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Quicksort}"-prinzip` that we prefer breaking between the English part and the German part rather than breaking inside any of the two parts?

Comment: Whatever else you do, I'd be sure to rewrite `Map/Reduce-Konzept` and `Assume/Guarantee-Spezifikation` as `Map\slash Reduce-Konzept` and `Assume\slash Guarantee-Spezifikation`, respectively. By using the macro `\slash` rather than by hard-coding the `/` symbol, you're indicating to TeX that it's ok to insert a line break after the `/` symbol (without inserting a hyphen symbol, of course).

Comment: @Mico Got it; thanks! But isn't `\slash` simply `/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty` (line 597 of latex.ltx)?  If we wish to tweak penalties, we should probably say `/\penalty something_else` anyway (as `/\penalty2` in my example), don't we?

Comment: Please say a bit more about the language-related structure of your document. E.g., is it almost entirely in German, with a few choice words derived from English (the (in)famous "Neudeutsch"?) strewn in? Or does the document contain passages that are genuinely in English?

Comment: @Mico It's a book written in German. The only English parts are a few English (compound or simple) words, a few English abbreviations, a few short English phrases, a few mixed English-German compounds, and some full English sentences in the bibliography (e.g., the titles of certain cited literature). I also use a few other languages in the same way as English.

Answer (score 1):

You've told us that your document is almost entirely in German, apart from "a few English (compound or simple) words, a few English abbreviations, a few short English phrases, a few mixed English-German compounds, and some full English sentences". I take it that you know how how to deal effectively (within the `babel` framework) with short English-language phrases. Abbreviations and acronyms should not (ever?) be allowed to be hyphenated, right? The main issue, then, is how to deal with the mixed English-German compound words, of which you've provided four choice examples: `Quicksortprinzip`, `Pipes-and-Filters-Architektur`, `Map/Reduce-Konzept`, and `Assume/Guarantee-Spezifikation`.

My view is to treat these cases as if they were (mostly) German-language constructs. Thus, do use `\slash` instead of `/` to allow line-breaking, and do make use of the babel-german `"=` shortcut to allow hyphenation of the components of compound hyphenated words. Finally, use `\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{....}` to indicate where *not* to hyphenate certain words. E.g., left to its own devices, babel-german "finds" tso hyphenation points in both `assume` and `reduce`; I suggest suppressing hyphenation entirely for these two words.

[image]

I've used LuaLaTeX to compile this test document, mainly so that the hyphenation of the first word in a paragraph is enabled .

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
%% suppress hyphenation for selected English words in a German-language context
\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{guarantee filters reduce assume}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{1sp}

\let\oldslash\slash
\renewcommand\slash{\oldslash\hspace{0pt}}
\begin{document}

Quicksortprinzip

\smallskip
Pipes"=and"=Filters"=Architektur

\smallskip
Map\slash Reduce"=Konzept

\smallskip
Assume\slash Guarantee"=Spezifikation
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's possible to define `\hyph` similarly to `\slash` to allow what follows to be hyphenated.  That's often done for TUGboat.

Comment: First, thanks! Second, any way to provide a stronger preference for breaking “Pipes-and-Filters-Architektur” before “Architektur” than before and after “and-”? Third, won't all these compounds be internally treated as German the way you wrote them?

Comment: You ask a really important question: Is it possible to indicate that not all possible break points are created equal and that, instead, to indicate a preference for line breaking to occur at only a subset of all possible breakpoints? Probably unsurprisingly for you, German authors are particularly interested in this topic, since long compound words -- e.g., Donauschifffahrtskapitän, which has 6 possible hyphation points, of which 2 (Donau-schiffahrts-kapitän) should be preferred quite strongly -- are quite common. Sadly, AFAICT, no ideas on this topic have reached implementation stage to date.